# Deprecated AR Camera with wew Google Tango Unity SDK Version

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

It seems like google is pushing new releases of the Tango Unity SDK quite often.

With the new version (Gankino), the "Tango AR Camera" is now deprecated. The point is that it is still used by all the examples.

Do you know if Google has planned to also update the examples?

Do you know if we can simply replace any Camera with the new "Tango Camera" prefab?

In my case, I am working on an app based on the Area Learning example, but I have no idea how to deal with ADF with the new SDK version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had problems getting the Google Tango examples to work with the newer (non-deprecated) Tango Camera prefab. If you simply replace the Tango AR Camera prefab with the Tango Camera, you will see a white background instead of the image from your phone's camera. This is because Tango Camera does not have the Tango AR Screen script attached to it by default. If you attach the Tango AR Screen script to the Tango Camera everything should work properly in most cases that I have seen. To get a basic working configuration for something like the Tango Placing Virtual Objects in Augmented Reality (Kitty) Tutorial, simply follow the tutorial instructions AND add the Tango AR Screen script to the Tango Camera. This is using Unity 5.6.1f1, Android 7.1.1, Android SDK Tools 25.2.5 (this older version is required for building with Unity at the moment, it seems, but should not affect the solution I have provided above), and Tango Unity SDK 1.53.

Comment: I was always getting the white background instead of the camera, as a solution, I changed 'Tango Camera' > Camera > Clear Flags to 'Solid Color'.

Answer (score 1):

As of Tango Unity SDK Ikariotikos (Version 1.54, June 2017), the Tango AR Camera is still deprecated. The Tango AR Screen is added by default to the new Tango Camera, but it is not enabled. I was able to get the tutorials to work by clicking the checkbox to enable the Tango AR Screen. I also had to set Clear Flags to Solid Color in order to avoid a strange trailing of my AR objects. My Tango Camera settings are below. Keep in mind that this is Unity 5.6. I had to downgrade from Unity 2017.2 in order to get Tango to work (https://github.com/wrld3d/unity-api/issues/20).

I am new to Tango development, so there may be better solutions.[image]